# Is the trainable parameter saved when saving a tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a model that have some of its first layers frozen and the other ones not frozen. Then I save this model using `model.save(path)`. When I'll load it using `load_model(path)`, will the correct layers still be frozen or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trainable parameter is **saved** while saving a model.
Example :

```
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.layers[-1].trainable = False
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
)

model.save('test1')
model.save('test2.h5')

test1 = load_model('test1')
test2 = load_model('test2.h5')

for layer in model.layers:
  if layer.trainable:
    print('Not frozen')
  else:
    print('Frozen')

for layer in test1.layers:
  if layer.trainable:
    print('Not frozen')
  else:
    print('Frozen')

for layer in test2.layers:
  if layer.trainable:
    print('Not frozen')
  else:
    print('Frozen')
```

Output :

```
Not frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Not frozen
Frozen
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear from the documentation but my best guess is the layers are frozen. You could test this by loading the saved model then try:

```
for layer.model.layers:
    print(layer.name, layer.trainable)
```